# Jenkins error local repository Failed to connect to repository

Tags: azure, jenkins, development-environment

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h -- E:\Work\upskill\new.py HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout: stderr: fatal: invalid gitfile format: E:\demo\hello.py fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Do anyone have the solution , I am trying to access a local repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Push all local branches to the remote, and set each local branch to track the corresponding remote branch using any SCM e.g. GitHub,Bitbucket,Gitlab

OR

you need to run your site locally with HTTPS using mkcert, To use HTTPS with your local development site and access https://localhost or https://mysite.example (custom hostname), you need a TLS certificate. But browsers won't consider just any certificate valid: your certificate needs to be signed by an entity that is trusted by your browser, called a trusted certificate authority (CA).